# Alertas con react-alert no se muestran

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

estoy usando react-alert y demás para mostrar alertas en las validaciones de formularios y en otros casos, pero no se muestra ninguna alerta en ningun caso. Desde que empecé a usar react-alert sin antes implementarla en las validaciones no me funcionó. Leí algo sobre que al momento de exportar la alerta debía hacerlo con withAlert()(Alerts) o solo withAlert(Alerts) pero en ningun caso funciona.

Tengo el siguiente código:

Aquí configuro las alertas

```
import React,{Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import {withAlert} from 'react-alert';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
export class Alerts extends Component{
   static propTypes={
      error:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      message:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   };
   componentDidMount(prevProps){
      const{error,alert,message}=this.props;
      if(error!==prevProps.error){
     if(error.msg.nombre) alert.error(`Nombre:${error.msg.nombre.join()}`);
     if(error.msg.sustanciaActiva) alert.error(`Nombre:${error.msg.sustanciaActiva.join()}`);
     if(error.msg.cantidad) alert.error(`Nombre:${error.msg.cantidad.join()}`);
     if(error.msg.precio) alert.error(`Nombre:${error.msg.precio.join()}`);
     if(error.msg.non_field_errors) alert.error(error.msg.non_field_errors.join());
     if(error.msg.username) alert.error(error.msg.username.join());
      }
      if(message!==prevProps.message){
     if(message.deleteProduct) alert.success(message.deleteProduct);
     if(message.addProduct) alert.success(message.addProduct);
     if(message.passwordNotMatch) alert.error(message.passwordNotMatch);
      }
   }
   render(){
      return <Fragment/>;
   }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
   error:state.errors,
   message:state.messages,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAlert()(Alerts));
```

Aquí incluyo las alertas en la App.

```
import React,{Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';
import {positions,Provider as AlertProvider} from 'react-alert';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route,Switch,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './layout/Header';
import Dashboard from './products/Dashboard';
import Alerts from './layout/alerts';
import Login from './accounts/Login';
import Register from './accounts/Register';
import PrivateRoute from './common/PrivateRoute';
import {loadUser} from '../actions/auth';
import store from '../store';
const alertOptions={
   timeout:3000,
   position:positions.BOTTOM_CENTER,
};
class App extends Component{
   componentDidMount(){
      store.dispatch(loadUser());
   }
   render(){
      return(
     <Provider store={store}>
     <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate}{...alertOptions}>
     <Router>
     <Fragment>
        <Header/>
        <div className="container">
           <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
           </Switch>
        </div>
     </Fragment>
     </Router>
     </AlertProvider>
     </Provider>
      )
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Veo que importas tu componente de Alerts dentro del componente de App, pero no veo que lo utilices en ningún lado, el componente lo usas dentro de las rutas ? puedes intentar meter tu componente de Alerts dentro del App?

Comment: @JesusOchoa efectivamente, no estaba utilizando el Alerts, pero además de eso, en el componente alerts no estaba dejando que se actualize el componente con la propiedad componentDidMount, tenía que usar componentDidUpdate, gracias.